# how to set kendo ui autocomplete width with css?

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I set the width of an autocomplete using css? I know I can set it up when I set up the width when I declare it, like so.

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("test").HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:400px"}))
```

But I want to know how to do it in css.  I tried the following and it didn't work

```
 .k-autocomplete .k-header
{
    width: 300px;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
.k-autocomplete.k-header {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Remove the space between CSS class selectors.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [their documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/autocomplete/overview)

```
var autoComplete = $("#autoComplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");

// set width of the drop-down list
autoComplete.list.width(400);
```

Seems a bit odd that this isn't part of the configuration when you initialize.. maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

For me in 2020, the answer was simply:

```
.k-autocomplete {
    width: 300px;
}
```